# VBA loop and variables - find blank row and put row number in variable

Tags: vba, excel

[image]I'm writing a Macro which loops though the Excel data, which is sorted by column A and inserts a blank row if the the values for coulmn are different from the one above. This separates my data in groups by column A.

I then want to sum the value of column d of the separated groups. I have most of my code working underneath, however its the startCell variable I am having trouble with. I know what I want to do, but cant get the logic right, can someone please help sum up those individual groups.

Many thanks

```
Sub PutARowInWithFormula()
  Range("A3").Select

  Dim startCell As Integer
  Dim endCell As Integer

  startCell = 3
  endCell = 0

  Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Else
      ' I need the bottom code to execute only once in the loop
      ' startCell = ActiveCell.Row
      ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert

      ' move to column d
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select

      endCell = ActiveCell.Row - 1
      ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sum(d" & startCell & ":d" & endCell & ")"

      ' move back to column a
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Select

      'move 2 rows down
      ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select
    End If
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: can you copy some sample data below your question (by updating it - not by a comment)? I meant a screen of what you need to sort/group and what you expect as the answer.

Comment: why don't you just use a pivot table which can summarise your totals by day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am too wondering, why you don't use a PivotTable or just create this using worksheet functions, which is possible too. Also I do not really like this attempt with selections, but its your way, and I respect that. It even seems to be a quite good example of a situation, when it might be a *good* idea to use them. Because right now, any other way I could think of, to do this in VBA, seems to be more complicated.

So here is a fix up of your code:

```
Sub PutARowInWithFormula()
  Range("A2").Select

  Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Else
      ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert

      'you can use the offset directly
      'by using an improved formula, you do not need to know start and end row.
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = _
        "=SUMIF(A:A,OFFSET(INDIRECT(""A""&ROW()),-1,0),D:D)"

      ' move back to column a and move 2 rows down
      ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
    End If
  Loop
End Sub
```

*Edit*

Ok, found a way easier way to do *nearly* the same thing:

```
Public Sub demo()
  UsedRange.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=4
End Sub
```

This function is also available through the *ribbon-menu -> data -> sumsum*

To avoid the error-message, you just need to have a title-row for your data, like:

*DATE | NAME | COUNTER | VALUE*